# React Native ERROR: Android tasks have already been created. Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

My react native app doesn't build after updating Android Studio and Gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        afterEvaluate {project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 27
                    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
                }
            }
        }

        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\mobileinstein.app\android\build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Android tasks have already been created.
     This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
     android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
     Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
     continue configuring the model.
   > Android tasks have already been created.
     This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
     android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
     Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
     continue configuring the model.
   > Android tasks have already been created.
     This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
     android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
     Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
     continue configuring the model.
   > Android tasks have already been created.
     This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
     android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
     Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
     continue configuring the model.
```

The error seems to be in "subprojects" section but I need it. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and invalidating cache / restart Android Studio?

Comment: Just change order of google() and jcenter()

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? I have exactly the same problem, any help would be helpful, thx!

Comment: @mjrdnk try to run gradle cleanup task. I think that was what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Change order `google()` then `jcenter()` that should work